# Cocoa Architecture advice for a small IDE

Tags: cocoa, ide, project, nsdocument

I have embarked in a personal project for developing a simple Cocoa IDE for microcontroller programming on Mac OSX Snow Leopard. As the programming is not a an issue, I have some difficulties choosing the architecture to blueprint the high-level blocks of the application. I was thinking about:

1. Have the possibility to set project details, similar to what XCode does when user creates a new project; probably the possibility to include accessory views for project details that might be stored in user defaults or plists.

   Have the possibility to save the project in a custom, specific filetype, with a specific extension that the app will be owner of (document-based app).

   Have the possibility to add new files to the project, in particular h-file headers that will be automatically included for compilation; when choosing new file, to have the possibility to choose the type of file (similar to XCode);

   Have a simple editor, text-view-based, for example, without syntax coloring, check, highlighting; however to design it in such a way to allow future development of syntax coloring/ check, via a `NSScanner`, for example;

   Have the possibility to auto generate a Makefile for compilation, based on any persistence method at choice.

   Have the possibility to log compiler verbosity into a logging view (text view?) either via `stdout` or other better approach;

   Using an `NSOutlineView` with a tree controller (for example) for file browsing (similar to the XCode's project files on left pane);

   Having the project packaged into folder-like project files, with `NSFileWrapper` for example (that will include the main.c file, additional header, the autogenerated Makefile and a plist for project settings etc);

   Having settings persistence using `NSUserDefaults` for project settings and application preferences via application-shared singleton (for example);

   Using some classes in the model component to connect with microcode compiler via `NSTask` and display compilation and upload results in the logging text view;

   etc

If any of you, with much more experience than me, would embark in such a project, what would be your choice of architectural components ? Same (split-views, text views, `NSTask`, filewrappers, outline views with tree controllers, separate app delegate from document and shared instance of document controller etc), or would you choose a different approach ? A much simpler one ?

I would appreciate any possible hint on this. Thank you for taking your time. If anyone interested, I will keep informed on the progress.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project, but SO isn't really the right forum to thrash out your program design. If you can distill out some actual concrete *questions* (that would have actual nitty-gritty *answers*) you'll probably get a better response.

Comment: Hi, Eimantas. Thank you for your comment. You are probably right, the amount of text is considerable. But providing a simple question like "how would you approach the architecture of a cocoa-based IDE" would have probably be met with, at best, questions like "please provide more details". So I kindly ask for your indulgence on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say start with the user interface. Think about how the user will use your IDE.

Will it work like Xcode 3? Xcode 4? A simplified version of either? Another existing IDE? Something largely or completely original?

Draw sketches, whether on paper or in your favorite image editor. Try different layouts. Sketch the same thing different ways and compare them.

Think of the different things the user will need to do. How will they do it? Does one method come at the expense of another task? Is it worth it?

Once you have an idea of how your user interface will work, you'll find that your model and your controller layout will follow from that.

---

It sounds like you've thought about at least some of this already, so I'll address only a couple of your specific items:

> - Have a simple editor, text-view-based, for example, without syntax coloring, check, highlighting; however to design it in such a way to allow future development of syntax coloring/ check, via a NSScanner, for example;

Parsing C code with NSScanner will be a bag of hurt. There may be a suitable text view/syntax-colorer already existing that you could use; I, for one, would do a good thorough search before embarking on such a task myself. If I had to write something like this from scratch, I'd look into [what Clang can do for me](http://clang.llvm.org/features.html#libraryarch).

> - Having the project packaged into folder-like project files, with NSFileWrapper for example (that will include the main.c file, additional header, the autogenerated Makefile and a plist for project settings etc);

Beware: NSFileWrapper used to not understand .svn directories. That was a big complaint about Interface Builder back in the 2.x days. They fixed it in IB years ago, but I'm not sure NSFileWrapper ever got the fix.

Comment: Dear Peter, Thank you for your answer. Appreciate your taking time in this. I was considering similar steps to be taken regarding the interface (sketches etc), however, my biggest problem now is to understand whether there is an "accepted design pattern" or "best practice" (though not the correct terms, probably) that could guide the overall creation of an IDE, with specifics on cocoa fw classes, since I really don't want to reinvent the wheel. For example (a simple one) is it recommended to use split views or separate views for the "pannel-like" appearance of the IDE ? etc. Thanks again.

Comment: @Tom: A split view doesn't save you from making separate views; it clarifies the division between them and enables the user to adjust their proportion. I recommend using a split view for any master/detail layout.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I will dive deeper. Warmest regards, Tom

Comment: Peter, the project is on the right tracks. Thanks again for your help. Tom